# Changing an attribute of a frozen class in attrs

Tags: python, python-attrs

```
import attr
@attr.s(slots=True, frozen=True)
class C:
    url = attr.ib(type=str)
    x = attr.ib()
    y = attr.ib()
    z = attr.ib(default=10)
    
    @y.default
    def _any_name_except_a_name_of_an_attribute(self):
        return self.x + 1
    
    @url.validator
    def map_url(self, attribute, value):
        if value == "apple":
            self.url = "mango"

print(C(x=4,y=5, url="apple"))
```

I was hoping to find a way to change the url when its initialized to a particular value, without loosing the frozen property of the class, would that be possible anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the passed-in value is what a [converter](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#conversion) is for:

```
url = attr.ib(type=str, converter=lambda x: 'mango' if x=='apple' else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this could be achieved post-initialization using the [attr.evolve](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attrs.evolve) method, which creates a copy of an instance with the specified changes applied to it, thus maintaining the frozen constraint on class instances.

As an aside, this kind of modification of immutable instances is found everywhere in functional programming, such as scala's case class [copy method](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/case-classes.html#copy-method).

```
>>> c = C(x=4, y=5, url="apple")

# create a new instance with a different url
>>> attr.evolve(c, url="banana")
C(url='banana', x=4, y=5, z=10)

# original instance remains unchanged
>>> c
C(url='apple', x=4, y=5, z=10)
```